# The misjudge in yolov5

Tags: machine-learning, yolo, yolov5

I train a single class model with yolo5.The dataset which contains 400 images is split into train,val and test dataset.Here is a notebook of train code[train code](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1gDZ2xcTOgR39tGGs-EZ6i3RTs16wmzZQ).
The train get a well result .However,when i build a real-time object detection application with the exported model,the result is not satisfactory,it can recognize the object as expected.But there are many misjudge in the detection.The detection result:
[result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OyTNv.jpg)

In the result,there is only one pepsi,why the timestamp and the other small area are recognized as pepsi.

Can someone tell me  the reason of the result?

Answer (score 0):

Your question lacks a lot of specifics, but my guess is that you have not trained on nearly enough images.  400 is just a toy and most likely resulted in overfitting.

You are going to want to look at a dataset like COCO or ImageNet to get reasonably generalized results.